# Не могу установить PostgreSQL в Ubuntu

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
alex-conquer@LAPTOP-EVM4AADF:/mnt/c/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/pythonProject18$ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
Reading package lists... Done
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctlcluster 12 main start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/12/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Setting up sysstat (12.2.0-2ubuntu0.2) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/sysstat with new version
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/sar.sysstat to provide /usr/bin/sar (sar) in auto mode
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sysstat.service → /lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service.
Setting up postgresql-contrib (12+214ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up postgresql (12+214ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.15) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.7) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link

alex-conquer@LAPTOP-EVM4AADF:/mnt/c/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/pythonProject18$ sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Comment: пытаюсь установить в первой команде , потом проверяю нормально ли скачалось

Comment: В ошибке же пишет что у вас система без поддержки systemd. А вы пытаетесь запустить сервер постгреса командой для systemd.  По идее тут такая же проблема, а ответ очень подробный: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate